# ¿Cómo colocar un pop-up en el mismo sitio pero relativo a donde te encuentras?

Tags: css, materialize

Si tengo una `<form>` preparada que aparezca en modo "pop-up" cuando clicko el `<div>` con el id #popup_help

```js
function openForm() {
    document.getElementById('help-pop-up').style.display = "block";
 }
```

```css
#help-pop-up{
    display: none;
    background: #35393C;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    right: 5vh;
}
```

```html
 <div id="popup_help" class="fixed-action-btn">
        <a href="#modal1" onclick="openForm()" class="btn-floating red btn-large">
          <i class="large material-icons">help</i>
        </a>
      </div>
 
 
 <form id="help-pop-up" >
              <div id="modal1">
                <div class="white-text" >
                    <h4>¿Tienes Alguna Pregunta?</h4>
                    <p id="contacto-p">Nos pondremos en contacto contigo</p>
                  <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                  <input placeholder="email" id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate white-text">
                  <label for="icon_prefix"></label>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                  <input placeholder="telefono" id="icon_email" type="email" class="validate white-text">
                  <label for="icon_email"></label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Enviar
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                  </button>
            </form>
```

Actualmente con ese CSS me aparece en un sitio fijo en la página. Cómo puedo hacer para que aparezca a la izquierda en cualquier posición que estés en la página (es decir, que no te transporte hacia el lugar donde aparece sino que aparezca "dinámicamente" a la izquierda siempre).

Comment: Cambiar el `absolute` por `fixed` y el `right` por `left`

Comment: @Roy gracias. Juraría que probé en poner fixed pero por algo que debí tocar no me funcionaba y me preguntaba si era algun problema con materialize. Gracias!

Comment: De nada, suerte! agrego la respuesta para dar como válida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el **css** del modal `#help-pop-up`
 - position: `absolute` por `fixed`
 - la propiedad `right` por `left`

```
#help-pop-up{
    display: none;
    background: #35393C;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10vh;
    left: 5vh;
}
```

[CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)